# How to refresh bootstrap table data

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have one bootstrap table with the following code.

```
<table id="tblPendingRequests" data-height="300">
   <thead>
     <tr>
         <th data-field="Version">Version</th>
         <th data-field="Env">Env</th>
         <th data-field="Release">Release</th>
         <th data-field="CreatedBy">Created By</th>
         <th data-field="Action">Action</th>
     </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

added below references also.

```
function loadData(){
    $(function () {
        $('#tblPendingRequests').bootstrapTable({});
    });
}
```

Then I am loading some data to this table with the following lines of code

```
var mydata = { 
    "Version": data[index].DeploymentName, "Env": data[index].EnvName, 
    "Release":data[index].ReleaseName, "CreatedBy": data[index].UpdatedBy  
    "Action": ActionButton 
};          
testData.push(mydata);
updateData(testData);
function updateData(myData) {
    $('#tblPendingRequests').bootstrapTable("append", myData);
}
```

It is diplaying the data properly. I have one project dropdown on the page. Onchange of the project name i want to populate this table with fresh data. It is not happening. It is appending data to existing table data which i dont want. How to refresh the table and load new data in the table.

Comment: link to `bootstrapTable` plugin?

Answer (score 6):

The method you have followed is correct except, in `mydata` a comma is missing before `Action`

Also make sure that the values like `data[index].DeploymentName` are existing.

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Cerlin/sjo0n4ro/)

**UPDATE**

Use `load` function instead of `append`

[**CHECK THIS**](http://jsfiddle.net/Cerlin/sjo0n4ro/1/)

Comment: Thanks you so much. I just checked your example on fiddle.  But i need to populate new data in the table every time i click the button. Its appending data to existing records.