# Fill in Bootstrap table after Ajax request (JSP and Spring MVC)

Tags: java, ajax, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc

Hi I try to fill in my tables in my JSP view after having send a variable into an Ajax function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function filterByDate() {

                var count = 680;

                $.ajax({
                    url : 'filterOnDate',
                    data : {
                        "count" : count
                    }, //here you send the daterange over an Ajax request and by default it's sended with a GET method
                    success : function(data) {
                        //alert(data); //here you will see an alert displaying the callback result coming from your spring controller
                        console.log("Request succeeded!");
                        console.log(data);
                    },

                    error : function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        if (xhr.status == 404) {
                            alert(thrownError);
                        }
                    }

                });
            }
        </script>
```

This Ajax request is send to a UserController who receive this variable and send it to the Model for performing an Hibernate search criteria in database.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/eblinb2b/filterOnDate", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody List<EblInvB2B> filterByDate(Model model, @RequestParam("count") int count) {

    // Fetch data from the DAO
    List<EblInvB2B> eblinb2b_filter_counting = accountSservice.findByDateRangeEB2B(count);

    // We add to the model (JSP page the list of EBLINVB2B)
    model.addAttribute("eblinb2b_filter_counting", eblinb2b_filter_counting);

    return eblinb2b_filter_counting;

}
```

I already checked if the hibernate query retrieve the information from the COLUMN table after I put a Debug breakpoint i see my List with objects.

This is the DAO method with Hibernate criteria:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public List<EblInvB2B> findDateRange(int count) {

    Criteria criteria = createEntityCriteria();

    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("count", count));
    return (List<EblInvB2B>) criteria.list();
}
```

What i'd like to do is to fill my table with a response to my Ajax only with the rows where i applied the criteria which is count that comes from my Ajax request it is equal to 680 it is an integer and should fill in my jsp table with only one row.

Just for information: I have a **Different** JSP view where I have and Update Button for populating mySql database it is in fact a batch that unmarshall XML files and put them into database. This is the usercontroller method :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/eblinb2b/OutInCompare", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String eblinb2bOutInCompare(Model model) {

    // Fetch data from the DAO
    List<EblInvB2B> eblinb2b_list = accountSservice.findAllEblInvB2B();

    // We add to the model (JSP page the list of EBLINVB2B)
    model.addAttribute("eblinb2b_list", eblinb2b_list);


    return "eblinb2bCompare";

}
```

Here i want to display in my view the list passed by my Controller method onto my JSP view. I don't know if it is correct? : **BOOTSTRAP PAGE**

https://jsfiddle.net/eaL38ejr/

Thanks to all for your help!

Comment: Are you getting data here `console.log(data);`?

Comment: @VinothKrishnan I have edited my main question maybe it will give you more insights on my problems thanks a lot!

Comment: In your controller it receives two params, but in your ajax you're sending only count not model object. That may be causing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should've load the bootstrap table again after getting data from ajax.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function filterByDate() {

        var count = 680;

        $.ajax({
            url : 'filterOnDate',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType:'json',
            data : {
                "count" : count
            }, //here you send the daterange over an Ajax request and by default it's sended with a GET method
            success : function(data) {
                //alert(data); //here you will see an alert displaying the callback result coming from your spring controller
                console.log("Request succeeded!");
                console.log(data);
                $('#tableID').bootstrapTable('load', data);
            },

            error : function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                if (xhr.status == 404) {
                    alert(thrownError);
                }
            }

        });
    }
</script>
```

Or do a refresh,

```
$('#tableID').bootstrapTable('refresh', {
    url: 'filterOnDate?count='+count
});
```

**Edit**

Ajax 406 indicates your request is not acceptable, hence you need to update your controller method like below.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/eblinb2b/OutInCompare", method = RequestMethod.GET, 
                    headers="Accept=*/*",produces = "application/json")
public @ResponseBody List<EblInvB2B> filterByDate(Model model, @RequestParam("count") int count) {

// Fetch data from the DAO
List<EblInvB2B> eblinb2b_filter_counting = accountSservice.findByDateRangeEB2B(count);

// We add to the model (JSP page the list of EBLINVB2B)
model.addAttribute("eblinb2b_filter_counting", eblinb2b_filter_counting);

return eblinb2b_filter_counting;

}
```

As well include `type` and `dataType` parameter's in your ajax request. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help and time. It seems that when i send the request no response is available. When I open Development tool view on Chrome I have this error: GET http://localhost:8080/gms/eblinb2b/filterOnDate?count=680 406 ()

Comment: 406 code of ajax indicates your method is **not acceptable**. Please check my updates in ajax and controller part.

Comment: It now says me "Faild to load Response Data" i have edited again my question as I give you my JSP table. Thank you so much for your patience

Comment: My request now works FINE I think the problem is in my view I don"t pass the data received when making the Ajax request into the bootstrap tables in the correct way..

Comment: Can you post you code relevant to bootstrap? As well show the data received from ajax.

Comment: A quick guess `$('#myTable').bootstrapTable('load', data);`, here you should give your table ID (i.e) `$('#dataTable').bootstrapTable('load', data);`

Comment: Checkout [Refresh data dynamically?](https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/issues/1363) and [How to refresh bootstrap table data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27915296/how-to-refresh-bootstrap-table-data) for more details. Mark it as answer and put upvote if it's useful.